# Find limits of sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ & $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $a_n=\int_{-\pi n}^{\pi n}|x|\sin x\;dx, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question :** Find the limits of the sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where

$$a_n=\int_{-\pi n}^{\pi n}|x|\sin x\;dx, \qquad b_n=\int_{-2\pi n}^{\pi+2\pi n}|x|\sin x\;dx, \qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

**My Efforts :** I have no clue how to solve it. $|x|$ is even, $\sin x$ is odd, thus `even*odd function`. Also, integral of odd function is $0$ so $a_n = 0$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like you have more than a clue. Do you know the limit of a constant sequence?

Comment: For $b_n$, can you use the same logic to simplify the integral? Then, can you say anything about how $b_{n+1}$ relates to $b_n$?

Comment: No but can you prove it rigorously?

Comment: $|x|\sin x$ is an odd function so every $a_n=0$. And $b_n=a_{2n}+c_n=c_n$ where $c_n=\int_{2\pi n}^{\pi+2\pi n}|x|\sin x dx=$ $=\int_{2\pi n}^{\pi+2\pi n}x\sin x dx>$ $\int_{2\pi n+\pi/4}^{3\pi / 4+2\pi n}x\sin x dx>$ $\int_{2\pi n+\pi/4}^{3\pi 4+2\pi n}2\pi n\cdot 1/\sqrt 2 dx=$ $\pi^2 n/\sqrt 2.$

Comment: $\int x\sin(x)\,dx$ is easily found by parts to be $\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+c$ so you can find $b_n$ exactly.